# Pycharm freeze after updating v5.0.1

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

After updated the pycharm 4.5.4 to 5.0.1, when i start it, it freeze at select proje section. After updating openjdk 7 to 8. Pycharm starts as normal. Bu this time when code assistance appears pycharm freeze again.

May be it's Debian stretch problem. Debian jessie working normaly.

## cat /etc/issue

```
Debian GNU/Linux stretch/sid \n \l
```

## uname -a

```
Linux gokhan 4.2.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.2.6-1 (2015-11-10) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## java -version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_72-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-internal-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b05, mixed mode)
```

Logs:

When close project;

```
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: [  13096]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - JDK: 1.8.0_72-internal
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: [  13096]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: [  13096]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - Vendor: Oracle Corporation
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: [  13096]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - OS: Linux
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: [  13096]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - Last Action: CloseProject
```

message:

```
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: WARN: Connection refused
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.tryActivate(SocketLock.java:182)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.access$300(SocketLock.java:49)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock$2.call(SocketLock.java:123)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock$2.call(SocketLock.java:112)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.underLocks(SocketLock.java:155)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:112)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lockSystemFolders(StartupUtil.java:263)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:101)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:34)  
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:90)
jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop[11138]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

idea.log:

```
WARN - napi.components.ServiceManager - com.jetbrains.python.console.PythonConsoleRunnerFactory requested as a service, but it is a component - convert it to a service or change call to ApplicationManager.getApplication().getComponent()
```

Comment: Same thing on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Opened a support request here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/81866

Comment: Have you tried to increase the memory?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the theme from "GTK+" to something else ("IntelliJ" oder "Darcula"). I did not have any crashes after that.

Comment: It seems to be working, but  after a certain time froze again

Answer (score 0):

Same here, temporarily solved by installing Oracle Java ( https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage ) and uninstalling OpenJDK